# Arithmetic operations on List of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am currently using Python 3.5.2. 
I have a dataset comprising of a list of dictionaries such as below (actual dataset has over 100 such entries):

```
MyList = [{"Class":1, "ID":123, "Name":"Sam", "Marks":90},
          {"Class":1, "ID":124, "Name":"Jack", "Marks":91},
          {"Class":1, "ID":125, "Name":"Dan", "Marks":92},
          {"Class":2, "ID":234, "Name":"Sammy", "Marks":82},
          {"Class":2, "ID":235, "Name":"Jacky", "Marks":85}]
```

I wanted to get the summary comprising as below:

```
ClassSummary = [{"Class":1, "TotalStudents": 3, "AvgMarks":91},
                {"Class":2, "TotalStudents": 2, "AvgMarks":83.5}]
```

where TotalStudents refer to count of "Name" in each Class
and AvgMarks refer to Average of "Marks" in each Class.

I am fairly new to list of dictionaries, so any leads on how to approach this would be of great help.

[Edit] Here is what I have tried so far:

```
class_set = set()
for dict in MyList:
    class_set.add(dict["Class"])
```

This gives me list of different classes available in my List. But I am not sure how to proceed further for subsequent arithmetic operations.

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: So far I have tried to extract unique set of Class in my list using "set"
    class_set = set()
    for dict in MyList:
        class_set.add(dict["Class"])

This gives me the available Classes, and then subsequently I was looking to loop through individual classes for further operations.

Comment: I don't see code on what you tried so here's instructions. Iterate thought the list with for loop, use conditions and do arithmetic.

Comment: If you could put the code that you have tried so far in the question it may help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit messy, but here is my solution that works fine:

```
ClassSummary = []
cls = 0
for d in MyList:
    if d["Class"] != cls:
        ClassSummary.append({"Class": d["Class"], "TotalStudents": 1, "AvgMarks": d["Marks"]})
        cls = d["Class"]
    else:
        ClassSummary[d["Class"]-1]["TotalStudents"] += 1
        ClassSummary[d["Class"]-1]["AvgMarks"] += d["Marks"]

for s in ClassSummary:
    s["AvgMarks"] /= s["TotalStudents"]
```

which gives `ClassSummary` as:

```
[{'TotalStudents': 3, 'AvgMarks': 91.0, 'Class': 1}, {'TotalStudents': 2, 'AvgMarks': 83.5, 'Class': 2}]
```

as you asked for!

Comment: Thank you Joe. 
This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated!